# How do I access the attr in a directive when testing - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs

I have a directive that I am trying to test.  Here is the directive:

```
App.directive('resize', function($animate) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.resize, function(newVal) {
      if(newVal) {
        $animate.addClass(element, 'span8');
      }
    });
  };
});
```

And here is my test:

```
describe('resize', function() {
  var element, scope;
  beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
    var directive = angular.element('<div class="span12" resize="isHidden"></div>');
    element = $compile(directive)($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();
    scope = $rootScope;
  }));

  it('should change to a span8 after resize', function() {
    expect($(element).hasClass('span12')).toBeTruthy();
    expect($(element).hasClass('span8')).toBeFalsy();
    element.scope.newVal = 'changed';
    scope.$apply();
    expect($(element).hasClass('span8')).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I am trying to access my `attrs` variable, change it, `$apply` and see if the `class` is changed like it is supposed to do.  I am not able to change the `attrs`.  I actually can't even find the way to access it.  How do I access the `attrs` in my test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element` is a [jqLite object](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element), or a plain jQuery object (if you're loading jQuery before AngularJS). Just use the `.attr()` method:

```
it('should do something on attr change', function(){
    element.attr('resize', 'newValue');
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

It isn't necessary to wrap the element in a new jQuery object: `$(element)` to use the `.hasClass(value)` method

Comment: I can set an attribute with that `element.attr('resize', 'newvalue')`, but when I try to access what `attrs` exist with `element.attrs()`, I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined`.  Why is that?

Comment: I have to specifically ask for the property, like `element.attr('resize')`